# 500 internal server error in codeigniter on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Here is uploading file function. which work's fine on localhost but i am not sure why this error occur because file permissions are ok and upload library is loaded fine and even doesn't show any error in log file.

```
$image_file   = $this->input->post('fileToUpload');
$update_date  = date('Y-m-d');

if($_FILES['user_image']['name'] != '') {
    $filename = 'user_image';    
}

$config = array(
    'upload_path'   => './uploads',
    'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg',
    'max_size'      => '2048',
);

$upload_data = $this->do_upload($filename, $config);

$this->db->where('pkuserid',$id);
$update_array = array(
    'firstname'   => $first_name,
    'lastname'    => $last_name,
    'headlines'   => $headlines,
    'summary'     => $summary2,
    'updated_date'=> $update_date
);

if($upload_data['condition']=='error') {
    echo json_encode(array('condition'=>'error', 'message'=>$upload_data['error'].' (User image)')); exit;
} else {
    $update_array['userpicture'] = $upload_data['upload_data']['file_name'];
}

$this->db->update('tblusers', $update_array);
return $update_array;
}

public function do_upload($fieldname, $config) {
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($fieldname)) {
        $error = array('condition'=>'error', 'error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        return $error;
    } else {
        $data = array('condition'=>'success', 'upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Upload folder snapshot:
[image]

Any Help will be appropriated. Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the class and file naming way for codeigniter as shown here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: you should have a look into the error log to get the error message. this would help a lot

Comment: @CROZET: Thanks for your response.  but in error log nothing will be shown when 'upload library' is uploaded success.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 : I think it's not naming issue because this code work's fine on my local machine.

Comment: Have you give the file permission on main folder and root folder?

Comment: @Jay Kareliya: i try for both folder's but not solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need a destination directory for your uploaded images. Create a directory at the root of your CodeIgniter installation called uploads and set its file permissions to 777.

```
$image_file   = $this->input->post('fileToUpload');
if($image_file){

     //load upload library
      $this->load->library('upload');

       // Specify configuration for File 1
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload($fieldname)){
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $update_array['userpicture'] = $upload_data['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }
}
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I've already done this, also try 0755, 0775 and 0777 but got the same response...

Comment: your url similar to this one: example.com/index.php/upload/ ?

Comment: log file show me this error when i changed the path: The upload path does not appear to be valid.

Comment: What exact path you got?

Comment: what is exact directory structure of upload folder?